# Problemas com o retorno de valores do $_POST

Tags: php, html, post, phpmailer

Eu estou enviando, através de um form, um e-mail. Eu faço os testes, mas ele recebe apenas 3 dos 4 campos, simplesmente é como se o campo com o `name` e `con_phone` não existissem.

HTML:

```
<form class="contact-form top_60" method="POST" action="mail.php">
  <div class="row">
    <!--Name-->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="con_name" name="con_name" class="form-inp requie" type="text" placeholder="Nome">
    </div>
    <!--Email-->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="con_email" name="con_email" class="form-inp requie" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <!--Telefone-->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="con_telefone" name="con_telefone" class="form-inp requie" type="text" placeholder="Telefone">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <!--Message-->
      <textarea name="con_message" id="con_message" class="requie" placeholder="Como podemos ajudá-lo?" rows="8"></textarea>
      <button id="con_submit" class="sitebtn top_30" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$con_name = $_POST['con_name'];
$con_email = $_POST['con_email'];
$con_telefone = $_POST['con_telefone'];
$con_message = $_POST['con_message'];

$mail->setFrom($con_email, $con_name);
//$mail->addAddress('contato@oficinadacriacao.com.br', 'Oficina da Criação');
$mail->addAddress('jakson1990@gmail.com', 'Oficina da Criação');
$mail->Subject  = 'E-mail enviado pelo contato do site.';
$mail->Body     = '

    Nome: ' . $con_name . '
    Email: ' . $con_email . '
    Telefone: ' . $con_telefone . '
    Mensagem:
    ' . $con_message . '
    Post: ' . json_encode($_POST) . '
    Mensagem enviada no dia ' . date("d/m/Y") . ' às ' . date("G:i") . '
    IP do usuário: ' . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

No e-mail eu recebi desta forma:

```
Nome: Jakson Juliano Fischer
    Email: jakson1990@gmail.com
    Telefone: 
    Mensagem:
    a1s2d1a2s1d
    Post: {"con_name":"Jakson Juliano Fischer","con_email":"jakson1990@gmail.com","con_message":"a1s2d1a2s1d"}
    Mensagem enviada no dia 10/05/2019 às 13:56
    IP do usuário: 000.002.125.75
```

Alguém já passou por este problema e consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Oi, altera class="form-inp requie" para class="form-inp require" e na parte do código que recebe o método POST altera $con_name = $_POST['con_name']; para $con_telefone= trim(addslashes($_POST['con_telefone']));, faz isso para os outros, e tenta enviar, pode ser porque você não está tratando as variáveis que recebem o método POST, e enviando direto, está quebrando.

Comment: Veja o que retorna dando um var_dump: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Infelizmente tentei fazer da forma com a qual o @EliseuB. menciou, mas não deu certo, em relação ao var_dump citado pelo Victor, resulta na mesma coisa que o json_decode($POST) retornou... É como se não existisse o campo com o name com_telefone :(

Comment: Ola @JaksonFischer, Não altere o titulo da pergunta para indicar que seu problema foi resolvido. Se você achou uma resposta diferente das propostas pela comunidade considere responder sua própria pergunta, mas tarde você poderá aceitar ela, isso pode ajudar a pessoas com o mesmo problema =D -- [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)  -- Se alguma reposta da comunidade te ajudou considere aceitar, essa seria a melhor forma de agradecer. =D -- [Tour]

Comment: @IcaroMartins obrigado pelo toque, vou fazer as alterações necessárias para atender as regras :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei o erro... Dentro do template tem um js responsável pelos inputs, ele limpa todos os valores enviados para o PhP pelo $_POST caso ele não esteja declarado, fazendo dessa forma que toda vez que ele identifique um valor a mais ele o delete.

Editei o documento e adicionei a nova con_telefone e ele está enviando normalmente.

Se posteriormente alguém mais tiver este problema com templates, olhe a pasta JS e veja se não tem um documento chamado main.js, provavelmente a mágica toda acontece dentro dele

Answer (score 1):

Concatene o conteúdo do e-mail de forma mais legível.

```
$mail->Body = nl2br("Nome: $con_name\n"
    ."Email: $con_email\n"
    ."Telefone: $con_telefone\n"
    ."Mensagem: $con_message\n"
    ."Post: " . json_encode($_POST). "\n"
    ."Mensagem enviada no dia " . date("d/m/Y") . " às " . date("G:i") . "\n"
    ."IP do usuário: " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "\n");
```

Comment: Eu estou utilizando o PhP Mailer, ele não aceita tags como \n, <br>, <strong>, dentre outras :/

Comment: Dá um print_r no seu $_POST, ele não recebe o valor preenchido em con_telefone ?

Comment: Consegui resolver, era um maldito arquivo JS lascando tudo kkkk
Muito obrigado de qualquer forma pelo tempo que tiraste pra tentar ajudar :D

Comment: use o btoa() para passar dados de um lado para outro no javascript ajuda muito, assim evita quebrar a sua string e a execução do código com alguns caracteres, e do outro lado decodifica o base64 que btoa converte. Boa sorte!